# Не отображается папка в которой лежат файлы на сайте

Tags: php

Добрый день дамы и господа.
У меня проблема в том что на странице не показывается название папки, они названы корневой директорией, которую я указываю в конце кода.

[image: скрин]

Знаний в php очень мало, но после долгого поиска я нашел вот этот код который более менее работает
Можете подсказать что не так в этом коде? Как сделать чтобы отображалось вместо "analize" то что нужно (там папки имеют названия месяцев)

```php
<?php

function frmtFolder($Entity){
    echo '<li style="font-weight:bold;color:black;list-style-type:none">' . $Entity;
}

function frmtFile($dEntry, $fEntry){
    echo '<li style="list-style-type:square">' . '<a href="' . $dEntry . '/' . $fEntry . 
'"> ' . $fEntry . ' </a>';
}

function listFolderFiles($dir) {
    $ffs = scandir($dir, $sort);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('index.html', $ffs, true)]);
    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1) {return;}
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($ffs as $ff) {
        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $ff)) {
            frmtFolder($dir);
        } else {
            frmtFile($dir, $ff);
        }
        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $ff)) {
            listFolderFiles($dir . '/' . $ff);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
listFolderFiles('analize');

?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: В `frmtFolder($dir)` надо передавать не `$dir`, а `$dir . '/' . $ff` или просто `$ff`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало как надо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `frmtFolder($dir)` надо передавать не `$dir`, а `$dir . '/' . $ff` или просто `$ff`. (@u_mulder)